Does $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) < \infty$ imply that $f(z)$ is bounded near $z_0$?
Does $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) < \infty$ imply that $f(z)$ is bounded near $z_0$? For example, do we have that since
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\sin z} = 1
$$
we have $\frac{z}{\sin z}$ is bounded near $z = 0$?

$<\infty$ has no meaning in $\mathbb C$.

If $f(z) \to L$ as $z \to z_0$, choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(z)-L|<1$ whenever $|z-z_0| < \delta$, or equivalently $L-1 <f(z)<L+1$ for all $z \in (z_0-\delta,z_0+\delta)$. So yes it is locally bounded whenever the limit exists and is finite.
